# How Javascript Date.parse() handle timezone with UTC format?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetime, timezone

In order to manage dates for different time zones for my mobile application developed with React native, my API stores in database and returns the dates in UTC format like this: `2020-09-06T11:07:12.647084Z`

I thought I had a specific procedure to do by sending myself to the API the phone's timezone via the React Native Localize package and the `rnlocalize.getTimeZone()` method so that the API could handle dates easily but I realized that simply passing the date in UTC format in the parse method of the Date object in native Javascript completely handled the different timezones in a magical way.

So, since I don't like magic, I was wondering how Javascript detects the phone's time zone and how the following code actually works internally:

```
Date.parse("2020-09-06T11:07:12.647084Z")
```

With this code, if I change my phone time zone to America/New_York or Europe/Brussel, the date is valid each time and for the same subject created, no matter the time zone, it tells me "4 minutes ago".

And what's the point of using React Native Localize if Javascript manages time zones, and more importantly, which one is more reliable?

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a time standard. "2020-09-06T11:07:12.647084Z" is an ISO 8601 format. While ECMA-262 does support a [very similar format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), the additional 3 digits in the decimal seconds is not supported so parsing is implementation dependent.

Comment: "2020-09-06T11:07:12.647084Z" represents a particular instant in time UTC, so regardless of the timezone of the device, it will always be the same time ago and the behaviour you're seeing is as expected. That is, if it was 4 minutes ago for a user in New York, then it was also 4 minutes ago for everyone everywhere (that's the point of using UTC, it's a universal time standard). However, if you were to show the local time, that **would** be different for timezones with different offsets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Nevertheless, and it's a big detail I forgot, when I say it's displayed on the screen "4 minutes ago", it's because that's what I need to display. On the other hand, if I log the dates I'm working on to display this "4 minutes ago", it's actually the dates that have been changed. I might as well have printed the local dates directly, it would have shown me 2020-09-06 07:00 in New York and 2020-09-06 13:00  in Brussels, and it's actually this part that seemed "magical" to me.

Comment: Thanks for the precision concerning UTC, it must have been funny to see me drop the word "UTC format" all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse` has some inconsistent behavior (see the second paragraph [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)), since the implementation varies. It may be fine to use here if you test thoroughly with all of your supported browsers and with all of the date formats you may store. The advantage of the native functionality is that it doesn't require any additional scripts.

The big plus for the library is that it will handle the inconsistency for you. It also looks like that localization library has a lot of other useful features, which you may or may not need for your application. Using the library will help maintain behavior in a more browser-independent way, but it does require the additional scripts.

My recommendation is to use the library. It will make your site work more consistently, and (without knowing everything your application is doing) I wouldn't expect the download of the extra script to be noticeable.

Comment: While your comments regarding Date.parse are correct, that's not the OP's issue. The "problem" is that there is no problem, the OP is seeing expected behaviour. A particular time UTC that is 4 minutes ago in one place will be 4 minutes ago in every place. Timezones are only an issue where the actual date and time are displayed using an offset other than UTC. The built–in [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) can be used, so a library might be convenient but isn't essential.